# Use Google Calendar API at Azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, google-api, google-oauth

I use  [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet) to download events from my google calendar.
It works on local machine fine. But id doesn't work after publish it on Azure because it use FileDataStore and app hasn't access to azure file system.

I also used [EFDataStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20502542/google-net-apis-any-other-datastore-other-than-the-filedatastore) but it doesn't work on Azure too.

Comment: So where do you *want* to store authentication information? Fundamentally, you need a suitable `IDataStore` implementation, but we don't know where you want to store the data.

Comment: I uploaded ASP.NET MVC site on Azure and I need to get events from google calendar. I can't use FileDataStore because web site hasn't access to azure file system

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but I'm asking where you want to store the cached authentication tokens as you can't use the file system. (You could do something in memory, but that doesn't work for multiple servers, or across server restarts.)

Comment: I can store token file at sqlite db, but I can't use FileDataStore from API with sqlite. I need to set the path

Comment: I know you can't use `FileDataStore`. That's why I said you needed a suitable `IDataStore` implementation. I suggest you implement that interface to talk to sqlite. (Although that sounds like an odd situation - sqlite is more often used on clients than servers, as far as I understand it.)

Comment: Filedatastore allows you to change the directory where it uploads to https://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/  IIR Azure will allow you to write in its current directory.  You could dump everything there.   Here is a collection of datastores that you may find helpful https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/a11851d51f13addd70264d01be1928bf

Comment: But note that using `FileDataStore` for just a local store has the issues I mentioned earlier in terms of scaling to multiple servers. You may well be better with something like Redis.

Comment: On Azure at FileDataStore(Server.MapPath(".")) I got error "Access is denied"

Answer (score 1):

I'm hosting on Azure too.

I created a datastore using Azure Table Storage.

Here's a [link to my gist](https://gist.github.com/NoelOConnell/0dee5fc144b0d56a2ce0aa0411316de9)

Just change it to your connection string and it should work.